# Smooth jump to target div when its inline css is display block

Tags: jquery

I've a very long form on which the `submit button` is initially at the middle and once user scroll past the `submit button`, the button gonna be sticky.

Now, the form error text is at the end of the form and it is initially hidden, and if got error it will change to `display: block;` in inline css.

**I want to make it when the error is in `display: block;` , the view window gonna automatically smooth jump to that text (not just jump to top because sometimes the `submit button` position is above the error), but it is not working.**

Any insight?

P/S : I've already search and test several codes, but it is not working.

```js
function moveScroller() {
var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
    var $scroller = $('#scroller');

    var move = function() {
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
        if(st > ot) {
            $scroller.css({
                position: "fixed",
                bottom: "4%",
                left: "1%"
            });
        } else {
            $scroller.css({
                position: "relative",
                top: "",
                left: ""
            });
        }
    };
    $(window).scroll(move);
    move();
}

$(function() {
  moveScroller();
});

$(".submit-button a").on("click",function(){
    $(".errors").css("display","block");
});

if($('.errors').css('display') == 'block') {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".errors").offset().top
            }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.errors {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero.</p>

<div id="scroller-anchor"></div>
<div id="scroller" class="submit-button"><a style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; background: pink;">SUBMIT BUTTON!</a></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero. <br> Integer pellentesque scelerisque diam ut egestas. Praesent arcu nunc, dignissim at cursus non, consectetur in erat. Nunc eu risus quis tortor sagittis fringilla sed eu mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce sit amet accumsan est. Curabitur eleifend augue sit amet feugiat bibendum. Aliquam maximus pharetra mi eget commodo. <br> Mauris mattis, est eu suscipit volutpat, magna purus efficitur quam, ac malesuada mauris mauris vel diam. Etiam sagittis nibh rutrum urna porta, cursus suscipit sem porta. Maecenas suscipit enim nec ipsum venenatis facilisis. Praesent tincidunt molestie nunc, non blandit quam mattis et. Suspendisse in mi interdum, ultrices leo eu, consectetur mi. Ut malesuada mi in urna ultrices aliquam. Praesent in tincidunt mi. Nam quis finibus mauris. <br> Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam in aliquet arcu. Vivamus quis tellus nec augue congue molestie. Duis a diam nec velit malesuada luctus. Duis pretium consequat sodales. Curabitur posuere nunc eget ipsum condimentum consequat. Fusce suscipit id velit sed sollicitudin. Cras congue a felis vitae semper. Suspendisse faucibus porttitor lectus, non porta arcu tempor vitae. Sed vitae vestibulum justo, id pulvinar massa. Ut non libero non urna rutrum venenatis. Curabitur eleifend interdum justo quis rhoncus. Praesent volutpat leo a egestas elementum. <br> Curabitur at leo fringilla, dignissim turpis at, semper ante. Aliquam eu finibus risus, eget ultrices mauris. Phasellus non neque vel tellus tempus vestibulum rhoncus vitae mauris. In consectetur, justo vel lacinia auctor, lectus nisl pharetra ex, non tempor enim ligula quis justo. Curabitur eu enim tincidunt, rhoncus mauris quis, scelerisque ipsum. Vivamus molestie consectetur turpis eu condimentum. Maecenas tincidunt leo quis vestibulum sagittis. Nulla et diam lobortis metus consequat faucibus. Ut molestie metus quis orci porta, non egestas libero tempus. Ut sagittis, enim in finibus euismod, odio felis egestas arcu, quis sagittis nulla enim vitae arcu. Nullam eu cursus urna. Maecenas quis accumsan dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras vel suscipit justo, vitae volutpat ipsum. In ut fermentum erat, non pharetra velit.</p>

<div class="errors">One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero. <br> Integer pellentesque scelerisque diam ut egestas. Praesent arcu nunc, dignissim at cursus non, consectetur in erat. Nunc eu risus quis tortor sagittis fringilla sed eu mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce sit amet accumsan est. Curabitur eleifend augue sit amet feugiat bibendum. Aliquam maximus pharetra mi eget commodo.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero. <br> Integer pellentesque scelerisque diam ut egestas. Praesent arcu nunc, dignissim at cursus non, consectetur in erat. Nunc eu risus quis tortor sagittis fringilla sed eu mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce sit amet accumsan est. Curabitur eleifend augue sit amet feugiat bibendum. Aliquam maximus pharetra mi eget commodo.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing display of the `.errors` class to block :

```
$(".submit-button a").on("click",function(){
    $(".errors").css("display","block");
    //here
    const errPos = $(".errors").offset().top;
    //adding  - 100 to bring it to a level of the eye that's noticeable.
    let options = {top: errPos - 100, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'};
    window.scroll(options)
});
```

Basically get the position of `.errors` with `offset().top` and then apply it to window.scroll as options.

Snippet here:

```js
function moveScroller() {
  var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
  var $scroller = $('#scroller');

  var move = function() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
    if (st > ot) {
      $scroller.css({
        position: "fixed",
        bottom: "4%",
        left: "1%"
      });
    } else {
      $scroller.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: "",
        left: ""
      });
    }
  };
  $(window).scroll(move);
  move();
}

$(function() {
  moveScroller();
});

$(".submit-button a").on("click", function() {
  $(".errors").css("display", "block");
  //here
  const errPos = $(".errors").offset().top
  let options = {
    top: errPos - 100,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  };
  window.scroll(options)
});
```

```css
.errors {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris
  vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales
  dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum
  quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero.</p>

<div id="scroller-anchor"></div>
<div id="scroller" class="submit-button"><a style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; background: pink;">SUBMIT BUTTON!</a></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris
  vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales
  dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum
  quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero. <br> Integer pellentesque scelerisque diam ut egestas. Praesent arcu nunc, dignissim at cursus
  non, consectetur in erat. Nunc eu risus quis tortor sagittis fringilla sed eu mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce sit amet accumsan est. Curabitur eleifend augue sit amet feugiat bibendum. Aliquam maximus pharetra mi eget commodo. <br> Mauris mattis,
  est eu suscipit volutpat, magna purus efficitur quam, ac malesuada mauris mauris vel diam. Etiam sagittis nibh rutrum urna porta, cursus suscipit sem porta. Maecenas suscipit enim nec ipsum venenatis facilisis. Praesent tincidunt molestie nunc, non
  blandit quam mattis et. Suspendisse in mi interdum, ultrices leo eu, consectetur mi. Ut malesuada mi in urna ultrices aliquam. Praesent in tincidunt mi. Nam quis finibus mauris. <br> Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam
  in aliquet arcu. Vivamus quis tellus nec augue congue molestie. Duis a diam nec velit malesuada luctus. Duis pretium consequat sodales. Curabitur posuere nunc eget ipsum condimentum consequat. Fusce suscipit id velit sed sollicitudin. Cras congue a
  felis vitae semper. Suspendisse faucibus porttitor lectus, non porta arcu tempor vitae. Sed vitae vestibulum justo, id pulvinar massa. Ut non libero non urna rutrum venenatis. Curabitur eleifend interdum justo quis rhoncus. Praesent volutpat leo a egestas
  elementum. <br> Curabitur at leo fringilla, dignissim turpis at, semper ante. Aliquam eu finibus risus, eget ultrices mauris. Phasellus non neque vel tellus tempus vestibulum rhoncus vitae mauris. In consectetur, justo vel lacinia auctor, lectus nisl
  pharetra ex, non tempor enim ligula quis justo. Curabitur eu enim tincidunt, rhoncus mauris quis, scelerisque ipsum. Vivamus molestie consectetur turpis eu condimentum. Maecenas tincidunt leo quis vestibulum sagittis. Nulla et diam lobortis metus consequat
  faucibus. Ut molestie metus quis orci porta, non egestas libero tempus. Ut sagittis, enim in finibus euismod, odio felis egestas arcu, quis sagittis nulla enim vitae arcu. Nullam eu cursus urna. Maecenas quis accumsan dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi
  tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras vel suscipit justo, vitae volutpat ipsum. In ut fermentum erat, non pharetra velit.</p>

<div class="errors" style="color: red;">One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris
  vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales
  dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum
  quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero. <br> Integer pellentesque scelerisque diam ut egestas. Praesent arcu nunc, dignissim at cursus
  non, consectetur in erat. Nunc eu risus quis tortor sagittis fringilla sed eu mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce sit amet accumsan est. Curabitur eleifend augue sit amet feugiat bibendum. Aliquam maximus pharetra mi eget commodo.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum odio vel velit ullamcorper facilisis. Curabitur nec sem hendrerit, consequat enim sollicitudin, ultricies lectus. In ultrices metus sed ante scelerisque luctus quis id lectus. Mauris
  vel ligula ex. Vestibulum justo enim, vulputate in ex vitae, consequat venenatis libero. Nam posuere elementum lectus et feugiat. Morbi dignissim egestas facilisis. Curabitur porta mi at quam suscipit, at rutrum ligula ullamcorper. Praesent et sodales
  dolor. Aenean erat erat, dictum sed leo ac, pharetra semper eros. Donec viverra tincidunt condimentum. Sed varius, ex finibus lacinia suscipit, nisl ipsum dapibus ex, ut fringilla lacus massa sit amet ligula. Fusce eu metus erat. Mauris pretium ipsum
  quis elementum gravida. Nullam ipsum tellus, iaculis sed sollicitudin non, dapibus id nisi. Ut orci lectus, volutpat ac orci quis, dapibus venenatis libero. <br> Integer pellentesque scelerisque diam ut egestas. Praesent arcu nunc, dignissim at cursus
  non, consectetur in erat. Nunc eu risus quis tortor sagittis fringilla sed eu mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce sit amet accumsan est. Curabitur eleifend augue sit amet feugiat bibendum. Aliquam maximus pharetra mi eget commodo.</p>
```

Comment: May I know why I cant use the if statement? Because although your method work, in my real life application, the submit button will go to thank you page if it's success. I just bind the errors with onClick here for demo purpose only.

Comment: @Nazrin Noorzan I'm not sure what you mean, I can't exactly understand what you typed to be honest, but you can pretty much apply my code anywhere in your application. On error basically apply the code that's inside the click event. It doesn't have to be a click event. It will work.

Comment: Basically you need to drop my code into the 'error' part of your real life app. If success go to another page, if error run this code that I gave you here. If you need something different from the current question, mark a solution here and ask it separately. That will work much better for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `$('html, body').animate` script to the `click` function after you change the display of `.error` to `block`.

Comment: May I know why I cant use the if statement? Because although your method work, in my real life application, the submit button will go to thank you page if it's success. I just bind the errors with onClick here for demo purpose only.

Comment: Because if statement runs only on the page load and not on submit error... you have to trigger it once the error occurs and not on the page load.

Answer (score 1):

right after showing the error div,

add the animate function to the errors div,

and add to his callback function of the animate, to call the moveScroller function,

after more test, my advice us to set scrollTop - 50 , in case clicking and showing the error from top of the page.

```
$(".submit-button a").on("click",function(){
      $(".errors").css("display","block");

      $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(".errors").offset().top - 50
      }, 2000, function() {
           moveScroller();
     });
});
```

Comment: May I know why I cant use the if statement? Because although your method work, in my real life application, the submit button will go to thank you page if it's success. I just bind the errors with onClick here for demo purpose only.

Comment: the if statement is not in the right place, it's need to bee in the place after you showing the error... in your example the if is in the end of the script and not in the event itself and will run only once when the page loaded, but will not run after the event of click and showing doe's...